# macOS - Is it possible to lock the time zone?

Tags: macos, mac, system-settings, timezone

I'm looking for a way of stopping myself changing which time zone my computer is in.

I would like to remain an admin with knowledge of the password so just making a non admin account would not work.

I think a lock on the GUI in system preferences would be sufficient. But if I could also stop myself from changing:

```
sudo systemsetup -settimezone timezone
```

That would be great too.

Thanks for the help - I'd be happy to clarify the problem if necessary.

A solution could be in the form of a bit of code that checks:

```
sudo systemsetup -gettimezone
```

every minute or so and changes it back if I have edited it.

Comment: Could you detail why you don't just stop fiddling with the setting? The simplest solution would just be to put the settimezone command in cron to run every minute ... no need to actual check if it was changed.

Answer (score 1):

Open Date & Time zone and tick the box, Set time zone automatically using current location.

[image]

Comment: If you don't want to reveal your "Closest City" you should remove city & country properly **but also the pin from Amsterdam** ;-)